# How to cancel Async spring method using two different apis

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, java.util.concurrent

I have got two APIs
**/books/generatreport** and **/books/cancelreport**
 what I am doing is when the user hits the first rest API books/generatereport it starts an async spring method which returns AsyncResult. 
 I am looking for is when the user hits books/cancelreport then it should cancel the task which was started by generatereport API.
 How can I share the AsyncResult between two rest APIs?

Comment: only way is to store it somewhere and retrieve it using some key

Comment: Where to store it any suggestions?

Comment: Try Concurrenthashmap

Comment: How can I share concurrenthashmap between two rest APIs? Please let me know

Comment: Also it's a multi clustered environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using servlet context solves my problem, as adding thing to servlet context is application level so this can be used for sharing information between two restful services.